# запрет вывода ресурса, который был выведен выше modx revo

Tags: php, cms, modx, revo

вывожу сначала последний добавленный автомобиль с описанием и фото, а ниже вывожу список всех остальных автомобилей, но почему-то ниже выводится и выше выведенный авто, хотя и указал оффсет=1

```
Последнее добавленное авто(первое выведенное авто с описание)
          [[!getResources?
      &parents=`23`
      &showHidden=`1`
      &tpl=`lostAuto`
      &limit=`1`
      &depth=`0`
      &includeContent=`1`
      &includeTVs=`1`
      &processTVs=`1`
      &tvPrefix=``
      &hideContainers=`1`
       &sortby=`{"publishedon":"DESC"}`
      ]]
```

вывод остальных авто(все остальные выведенные авто)

```
              [[!getPage?
          &elementClass=`modSnippet`
          &element=`getResources`
          &sortby=`{"publishedon":"DESC"}`
          &offset=`1`
          &showHidden=`1`
          &tpl=`AutoSaleTpl`
          &limit=`20`
          &includeContent=`1`
          &includeTVs=`1`
          &processTVs=`1`
          &tvPrefix=``
          &parents=`23`
          &hideContainers=`1`
          &pageLimit=`20`
          &pageNavVar=`page.nav`
          ]]
```

&offset=1 не срабатывает, все ровно выводит последнюю добавленную запись

Answer (score 2):

`offcet` при вызове `getPage` переопределяется так что ничего удивительного. К счастью можно эту задачку довольно просто решить через фильтры вывода модикса ( http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+%28Output+Modifiers%29 ). Поскольку "Последнее добавленное авто" выводится только одно, то можно в чанк `lostAuto` добавить строчку

```
[[+id:toPlaceholder=`lostAutoId`:notempty=``]]
```

после чего остается только добавить в вызов `getPage` еще один параметр -

```
&where=`{"id:!=":[[+lostAutoId]]}`
```